# Time is not changing when the timezone is set dynamically meanwhile its working when the timezone is set statically?

Tags: android

In this below code, the timezone changes when I give the local time zone statically as `asia/kolkatta` etc. But it doesn't change when I give it dynamically. I checked the value in local time zone when the user changes the timezone. It changed correctly and holds the value as `asia/kolkatta`.

```
public String cinverttoutc(String time) {
    String currenttimeformat = "";
    String twelvehourformat = "";

    try {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
        String Timezonename = timeZone.getID();
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(Timezonename);
        localtimezone = tz.getID();
        Log.i("localtimezone",localtimezone);
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dt = new Date();
        String dateis = sdf.format(dt);
        String dateandtime = dateis + " " + time;
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);
        SimpleDateFormat twelv`enter code here`ehour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        TimeZone utcZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(localtimezone);
        sdf1.setTimeZone(utcZone);
        Date myDate = sdf1.parse(dateandtime);
        sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        String Currentformat = sdf1.format(myDate);
        DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        Date now = readFormat.parse(Currentformat);
        currenttimeformat = timeFormat.format(now);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    return currenttimeformat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get local time zone using this method for everywhere

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
    Log.d("Time zone","="+tz.getDisplayName());
    localtimezone = tz.getID(); 
    Log.i("localtimezone",localtimezone);
```

Here you can change the format

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(localtimezone));
```